# Not able to hide modal popup using Java Script

Tags: javascript, java, asp.net, vb.net

'I have using modal popup and its working fine with button close event but not working with JavaScript  . Please help to me resolve this issue. '

`This My script`

```
<script>

 window.onload = function () {
 setInterval(function () {
 $("#btnclose").click().
 }, 3000);
 }

</script>
```

`this my modal popup that i have used`

```
 <div id="myModal" visible="false" runat="server" class="modal">
 <div id="modalcontent1" runat="server" class="modal-content">
 <div id="modalheader1" runat="server" class="modal-header">
 <h3>Message<br />
 </h3>
 </div>
<div id="madalbody1" runat="server" class="modal-body">
<p style="height: 60px; margin: 7px">
<asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</p>
</div>
<div id="modalfooter1" runat="server" class="modal-footer">
 <h3>
 <asp:Button ID="btnclose" CausesValidation="false" runat="server"   CssClass="allBtn blue" Text="CLOSE" />
 </h3>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

`I am using this as of now but for show and hide modal and now  i need to do that with JavaScript`

```
    Protected Sub btnclose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
     myModal.Visible = False
    myModal.Dispose()    
    End Sub
    
    Protected Sub displayMessage(msg As String)
    lblMsg.Text = ""
    myModal.Visible = True
    myModal.Style.Add("display", "block")
    lblMsg.Text = msg
    End Sub
```

Comment: You can't click anything without the user actually clicking

Comment: @Konrad how can i do the same thing if any suggestions or examples are then share .. i have used in my vb code as above i mentioned .